# Calculate in SQL Average number of active subscriptions per quarter

Tags: sql

I need a help please
I have a table with such fields: subscription_id, client_id, start_date, end_date.

Subscription is active when started but haven’t ended.

How I can calculate average number of active subscriptions per quarter?

I have issues with getting the active period for each subscription (between start and end date) and then by grouping it by quarters and years

I was trying this sQL ,but it dosen't work

```
`WITH total AS (
    SELECT 
        QUARTER(w.start_date) AS QUARTER_start, CONCAT("Y", YEAR(w.start_date)," ", "Q-", QUARTER(w.start_date)) AS "startYQ"   
        ,QUARTER(w.end_date) AS QUARTER_end, CONCAT("Y", YEAR(w.end_date)," ", "Q-", QUARTER(w.end_date)) AS "endYQ"
        ,count(w.subscription_id) as subscription_id
    FROM work w
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
    ORDER BY 2
)

SELECT t.endYQ, AVG(t.subscription_id) as avg_p
FROM total t
group by endYQ
order by 1;`
```

Comment: When a subscription ends in a specific quarted. Must it be count as active or not?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Peter, if ends in a specific quarter it must it be count as active.

Comment: jarlh, I'm using DBeaver